# Assigning a PHP variable to the results of an SQL query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Basically what i am trying to do is assign a variable to the results of an SQL statement.

In this example i want to count how many times the currently logged in customers id appears in a table called bookings. If this count is 5 or more than then $apply_discount=50. This can be used later in the page to discount a percentage amount.

I have tried for a few days now but i am very unfamiliar with using SQL withing PHP.

This is what i have so far :

```
<?php 
    $numofbookings = " number of times {$_SESSION['login']} appears in the booking table " //this is where im unfamiliar with the syntax
    // sql statement that counts how many times the currently logged in customers  id     {$_SESSION['login']} appears in the booking table 
    // database connection is done earlier on in the page with a db_connection.php include
    // table is called "bookings"
    // col that contains customer ids (which comes from {$_SESSION['login']} ) is called customer_id
?>


<?php 
    if $numofbookings =("5>")
    {
        $apply_discount=("50");
    }
    else
    {
        $apply_discount=("0");
    }
    // if the customer has 5 of more bookings then $apply_discount is 50,
    // this can be used later on to discount the % amount from the base price
?>

<?php
    $newprice = $base_price * ((100-$apply_discount) / 100); // calculation at bottom of page
?>
```

Comment: If you do calculation on strings and there is money involved, better use the binary calculator :-S

Comment: Sidenote: You should be doing `if ($numofbookings >5)` instead of `if $numofbookings =("5>")` Your quoted numbers won't be treated as integers.

Comment: @MichaelRushton, I think he wants someone to write all the queries and code for him. Without knowing the table structure and sample values, that's going to be difficult to help with. I'm willing to give hints and guidance, but I won't write the whole thing, especially as he appears to have no idea what he's doing with PHP.

Comment: There is none. OP's "wishing" that you/we will "fill in the blanks", as it were. @MichaelRushton

Comment: Posted the same thing (to Michael), probably at the very same time, if not by "milliseconds" lol @PhilPerry

Answer (score 0):

First you need to query the database to count the number of rows that meet your requirements:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('hostname', 'username', 'password', 'database');

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM bookings WHERE customer_id = ?")

$stmt->bind_param('i', $_SESSION['login']);

$stmt->execute();

$stmt->bind_result($numofbookings);

$stmt->fetch();

$stmt->close();
```

Then you need to fix your discount logic:

```
if ($numofbookings > 5)
{
  $apply_discount = 50;
}

else
{
  $apply_discount = 0;
}
```

Also, as you're using sessions you need to ensure that `session_start();` is included at the top of the file otherwise `$_SESSION` will be undefined.

You should look into the [`mysqli`](https://www.php.net/mysqli) or [`PDO`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) extension, the [`MySQL`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html) documentation, as well as `PHP`'s [control structures](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.control-structures.php) and [sessions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php).

Comment: Maybe an added note to show that `session_start();` will be required in all files used. ;-) I doubt the OP's experience in PHP/SQL.

Comment: Just an added note Michael. The `i` in `bind_param('i', $_SESSION['login'])` - The session stands at being a rather long alpha-numerical string.